# Is there a way to Server Side Rendering on a different server/service with NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, hubspot

I want to build a front-end app with Hubspot. I need to use SSR because of SEO purposes.
Unfortunately, Hubspot doesn't have a 'node server'.

Is there any way/solution so I can render the app somewhere else? Or do you know any other solution?

PS: I also use an external API to get data to display in the frontend app (beside Hubspot CMS).

Answer (score 1):

1.Dockerizing your project

2.Using `next export` (recommended for sites with static content)

Note that you cant run `Next js` project without node server so go on and use `Docker`for your project.

Comment: I cannot use Docker with Hubspot. It's a 3rd party service, without a 'server'.

Comment: In `next js` you can use custom server but it's also  Node js server ,unfortunately you can't change your server to other kind over server.